# Swizzling SKStoreProductViewController viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm having trouble swizzling viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear on SKStoreProductViewController. I need to know when a subclass of it gets presented by a 3rd party lib.

The code I use is:

```
- (void)swizzleFunnyStoreProductControllerAppear {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        SEL originalSelector = @selector(viewWillAppear:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(skViewDidAppearNotification:);
        NSString *viewControllerClassString = @"SKStoreProductViewController";

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(viewControllerClassString), originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(NSClassFromString(viewControllerClassString),
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(NSClassFromString(viewControllerClassString),
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (void)skViewDidAppearNotification:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ALFunnyViewControllerDidAppearNotification object:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    // calling the original method that is under the replaced name.
    [self skViewDidAppearNotification:animated];
}
```

When running it, I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FunnySKStoreProductViewControllerSubClass skViewDidAppearNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x144f1b830'
```

Using a breakpoint at [self skViewDidAp....] shows the class responding to selectors:

```
(lldb) po [self respondsToSelector:@selector(viewWillAppear:)]
true
(lldb) po [self respondsToSelector:@selector(viewDidAppear:)]
true
(lldb) po [self respondsToSelector:@selector(skViewDidAppearNotification:)]
false
(lldb) po [self respondsToSelector:@selector(skViewDidDisappearNotification:)]
true
```

I can't figure out why didAddMethod == NO for DidAppear, and why it works on the same class for DidDisappear?

Comment: Where exactly do you swizzle? in `+load`?

Comment: It's called during the instantiation of the library facade singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I think `SKStoreProductViewController` is use remote XPC service.
So you can not handle anything in your app.
It may handle by other system process.

If you use `recursiveDescription` on `storeProductViewController.view`

[image: recursiveDescription]

you can found the `_UIRemoteView`.